# Difference between nohup vs at now

Tags: linux, scheduling, nohup, at-job

It seems that there is no difference between *nohup* and *at now*, but maybe there are subtleties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `now` runs a command that can respond to `HUP` signal, where as the `nohup` runs a command that is immune to `HUP` signal.

Answer (score 2):

Ed Heal is right.  But another difference is that something run by `nohup` still has a controlling terminal, whereas something run by `at now` does not.

In addition to that, backgrounding something with `nohup` causes it to run immediately, whereas `at now` simply queues something to be run the next time [`atrun(8)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=atrun) runs.  In BSD unix, (FreeBSD/OpenBSD) at jobs are launched by `atrun` which is launched periodically by `cron` (or `launchd` in OSX).  In Linux, at jobs are run by at's own daemon, `atd`, which by default launches jobs every 60 seconds.

Other flavours of unix may have different strategies, but in most cases you'll probably find that jobs launched by `at now` are less immediate than jobs launched using `nohup`.

Comment: You are incorrect about the environment variables. Please take a look at http://linux.die.net/man/1/at (you can test this out by looking at the scripts that `at` creates (int `/var/spool/at
`). But +1 for the note about the controlling terminal

Comment: Hmm, right you are about environment.  Not sure what your platform is though -- on FreeBSD, jobs live in `/var/at/job/`.  Thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Your welcome. Have a pleasant weekend. It is also to know that as you can check.

Comment: What are the possible consequences of those differences, i.e. being immune to SIGHUP and having a controlling terminal?

Answer (score -1):

nohup tells the system to continue running even after you log out.
at is used to execute a command or multiple commands once at some future time.